# What is difference between creating custom attribute programmatically and via admin in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, admin-panel, custom-attributes, programmatically

Creating an attribute in the back end is easy, then why to create it as programmatically?

I like to know what is the difference between these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with the team with more than 1 member, then you need to sync all attributes with your team members. In that case, programmatically will help you.

If you are the only one on the team, then choose what is easy for you.

Another reason is: programmatically will assign attributes to all attribute sets automatically, otherwise, you need to create an attribute and assign it to all attribute set manually.

Comment: In addition to the above reasons, creating attributes programmatically is also useful when you are working on multiple instances, e.g dev, staging and production. I also find that I am sometimes working on a feature and the requirements for an attribute change. If I have a script that can add or replace the attribute programmatically, it saves a lot of time. Once you have the basic script created, it is much faster than using the admin. And finally, I didn't become a developer because I wanted to poke buttons and fill out forms by hand!